# Control Vlc with requests - java

Tags: java, http, request, vlc, remote-control

I want to control vlc with java code and its web interface using `http://localhost:8080`

The problem is I don't know how exactly I must use the http requests.
Here is some code I have written:

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since", "29 Oct 1999 19:43:31 GMT");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-1.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

//DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

OutputStream wr = con.getOutputStream();
if (line.split(":")[1].equals("Play")) {
      wr.write("requests/status.xml?command=pl_play".getBytes());
//          wr.write("play".getBytes());
    }
    else {
          wr.write("requests/status.xml?command=pl_stop".getBytes());
    }
    wr.flush();
    //wr.close();
    int status = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(status);
```

It mainly copy/paste from google.
Status returns 200..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to read the response from the connection!